# Why Android WebView is not loading youtube HTML5 iframe video?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I tried the following:

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    String playVideo= "<html><body><iframe width='200' height='143' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadData(playVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I only see thumbnail and then when I click on it the frame turns to black and does not load the video. I'm targeting API 15 and I have internet permission. How could I run the html5 youtube iframe video in Android webview?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475707/youtube-video-in-webview-doesnt-load. The guy had the same problem and seemed to get it working. Some of the comments suggest otherwise, but this may work for you.

Comment: You can take a look [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-i-frame-in-android-webview). It's pretty much the same with your problem.

Comment: any answer for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put this in your manifest

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android 3.0++, you must activate Hardware acceleration if your  android:targetSdkVersion is lower than 11. And, you must add this line:

```
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but I also had to add:  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1):

You are running on 2.3(GingerBread) or 4.0(ice Cream)?

If you are running on Ice Cream, you need to enable hardware acceleration.

If you are running on GingerBread, please refer to:
[WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)

Hope this helpgul.

Answer (score 0):

iframe works for me. But, I found out, when using Android Emulator on Windows for you tube video, the internet on Emulator will stop working after a while and I need to restart the emulator to get internet access. This has never happened on a Android Phone.

So, just check it on your browser to make sure there is internet connection.