# Android: Show youtube channel in webview using nexus 4

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, youtube-channels

I'm using a webview to show a youtube channel.
Using a nexus 4 it is not possible to play video (only audio starts).
I need to maintain the same graphic of the m.youtube.com/user/someuser so i can't use youtube api

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        final Activity activity = this;
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
          }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyOwnWebViewClient());   


        mWebView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com/user/someuser");//a channel youtube url     
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyOwnWebViewClient());      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    public class MyOwnWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

I have googled a lot but I can't find a solution.
The last code i took is from this post:

[Youtube Video in WebView doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475707/youtube-video-in-webview-doesnt-load/8490751#8490751)

Could anyone help me?

Thanks thousand

Comment: Did you enable hardware acceleration in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes...for the whole application and also for the activity

Comment: Disabling the hardware acceleration might be worth a try. I experienced strange render artifacts with the acceleration enabled